# Nested grouping with javascript (ES5)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects as following :

```
    [
        {"id":1,"lib":"A","categoryID":10,"categoryTitle":"Cat10","moduleID":"2","moduleTitle":"Module 2"},
        {"id":2,"lib":"B","categoryID":10,"categoryTitle":"Cat10","moduleID":"2","moduleTitle":"Module 2"},
        ...
        {"id":110,"lib":"XXX","categoryID":90,"categoryTitle":"Cat90","moduleID":"4","moduleTitle":"Module 4"}
    ]
```

I want to group this array by (`moduleID`,`moduleTitle`) and then by (`categoryID`,`categoryTitle`).

This is what I tried :

```
function groupBy(data, id, text) {

    return data.reduce(function (rv, x) { 
        var el = rv.find(function(r){
            return r && r.id === x[id];
        });
        if (el) { 
            el.children.push(x);
        } else { 
            rv.push({ id: x[id], text: x[text], children: [x] }); 
        } 
        return rv; 
    }, []);

}

var result = groupBy(response, "moduleID", "moduleTitle");

result.forEach(function(el){
    el.children = groupBy(el.children, "categoryID", "categoryTitle");
});
```

The above code is working as expected, but as you can see, after the first grouping I had to iterate again over the array which was grouped by the `moduleId` in order to group by the `categoryId`.

How can I modify this code so I can only call `groupBy` function once on the array ?

## Edit:

Sorry this might be late, but I want this done by using ES5, no Shim and no Polyfill too.

Comment: is it right, that `moduleID` is a string or a number?

Comment: @NinaScholz oops, my mistake, the `moduleID` is a string

Comment: btw, `find` is ES6.

Comment: Can you add some more test data and use Code Snippet?

Comment: @NinaScholz ooh! yes I noticed that, the project where I'm working on is using jshint, whenever I use some ES6 feature the build is failing telling me to use `esversion: 6`, but the weird thing is that it doesn't fail when I use `find`

Comment: @VivekAthalye ofc

Comment: Waiting for more test data. Btw, in your current test data of 3 records you have shown different `moduleTitle` for `"moduleId":"2"`. Is that expected or just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your function by using an array for the grouping id/names.

```js
function groupBy(data, groups) {
    return data.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        groups.reduce(function (level, key) {
            var el;

            level.some(function (r) {
                if (r && r.id === x[key[0]]) {
                    el = r;
                    return true;
                }
            });
            if (!el) {
                el = { id: x[key[0]], text: x[key[1]], children: [] };
                level.push(el);
            }
            return el.children;
        }, rv).push({ id: x.id, text: x.lib });
        return rv;
    }, []);
}

var response = [{ id: 1, lib: "A", categoryID: 10, categoryTitle: "Cat10", moduleID: "2", moduleTitle: "Workflow" }, { id: 2, lib: "B", categoryID: 10, categoryTitle: "Cat10", moduleID: "2", moduleTitle: "Module 2" }, { id: 110, lib: "XXX", categoryID: 90, categoryTitle: "Cat90", moduleID: "4", moduleTitle: "Module 4" }],
    result = groupBy(response, [["moduleID", "moduleTitle"], ["categoryID", "categoryTitle"]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version with path as `id`.

```js
function groupBy(data, groups) {
    return data.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        var path = [];
        var last = groups.reduce(function (level, key, i) {
            path.length = i;
            path[i] = key[0].slice(0, -2).toUpperCase() + ':' + x[key[0]];

            var id = path.join(';'),
                el = level.find(function (r) {
                    return r && r.id === id;
                });

            if (!el) {
                el = { id: path.join(';'), text: x[key[1]], children: [] };
                level.push(el);
            }
            return el.children;
        }, rv);

        last.push({ id: path.concat('NODE:' + x.id).join(';') });
        return rv;
    }, []);
}

var response = [{ id: 1, lib: "A", categoryID: 10, categoryTitle: "Cat10", moduleID: "2", moduleTitle: "Workflow" }, { id: 2, lib: "B", categoryID: 10, categoryTitle: "Cat10", moduleID: "2", moduleTitle: "Module 2" }, { id: 110, lib: "XXX", categoryID: 90, categoryTitle: "Cat90", moduleID: "4", moduleTitle: "Module 4" }];

    var result = groupBy(response, [["moduleID", "moduleTitle"], ["categoryID", "categoryTitle"]]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks you've save me :D, I just have one issue that I hope you can help me with, I want for the first level group (module) to look like this : `{"id": "MODULE:2",...}` and for the second level: `{"id" : "MODULE:2;CATEGORY:10" ...}` and for the last level `{"id": "MODULE:2;CATEGORY:10;NODE:1"}`

Comment: then you need to store the parent node as well for the name. where do you get `'NODE'` from?

Comment: `NODE` is just the last hierarchy in the array.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that the second version didn't work as expected I get the same array I give in input with a different id

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible (although may be a bit advanced) approach:

```
class DefaultMap extends Map {
    constructor(factory, iter) {
        super(iter || []);
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    get(key) {
        if (!this.has(key))
            this.set(key, this.factory());
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

Basically, it's the a `Map` that invokes a factory function when a value is missing. Now, the funny part:

```
let grouper = new DefaultMap(() => new DefaultMap(Array));

for (let item of yourArray) {
    let firstKey = item.whatever;
    let secondKey = item.somethingElse;
    grouper.get(firstKey).get(secondKey).push(item);
}
```

For each `firstKey` this creates a `Map` inside `grouper`, and the values of those maps are arrays grouped by the second key.

A more interesting part of your question is that you're using compound keys, which is quite tricky in JS, since it provides (almost) no immutable data structures. Consider:

```
items = [
    {a: 'one', b: 1},
    {a: 'one', b: 1},
    {a: 'one', b: 2},
    {a: 'two', b: 2},
]

let grouper = new DefaultMap(Array);

for (let x of items) {
    let key = [x.a, x.b];      // wrong!
    grouper.get(key).push(x);
}
```

So, we're naively grouping objects by a compound key and expecting to see two objects under `['one', 1]` in our grouper (which is one level for the sake of the example). Of course, that won't work, because each `key` is a freshly created array and all of them are different for `Map` or any other keyed storage.

One possible solution is to create an immutable structure for each key. An obvious choice would be to use `Symbol`, e.g.

```
let tuple = (...args) => Symbol.for(JSON.stringify(args))
```

and then

```
for (let x of items) {
    let key = tuple(x.a, x.b);      // works
    grouper.get(key).push(x);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm tied to use ES5.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki: `Maps` are perfectly polyfillable and so are `Symbols`

Comment: `may be a bit advanced`: And I thought I understand JS ... guess I need to go back to school ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
  const exit = Symbol("exit");

  function groupBy(arr, ...props){
    const root = {};
    for(const el of arr){
      const obj = props.map(key => el[key])
          .reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), root);
      (obj[exit] || (obj[exit] = [])).push(el);
    }
 }
```

So you can access it like:

```
  const grouped = groupBy(response, "moduleID", "moduleTitle");

 console.log( grouped[2]["workflow"][exit] );
```

You might leave away that exit symbol, but it feels a bit wrong to mix a nested tree with arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm tied to use ES5.

Comment: @ichigo just turn the arrow functions into regular functions and instead of the spread parameter just pass an array.

Comment: But what about `Symbol` ?

Comment: @ichigo `var exit ="ehdnwjfjsncisbxj";` just take a string that is very unlikely to collide with your values